# pick random rows from randomly selected userid's collection [mysql]

Tags: mysql, random

The scenario: (I'm using MySQL)

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE so_time_diff(
  OwnerUserId int(11),
  time_diff int(10)
);
```

There are many OwnerUserId's with each OwnerUserId having many time_diff values.

I would like to pick 1000 random distinct OwnerUserIds and for each OwnerUserId, pick just one random time_difference value.

I already got 1000 distinct OwnerUserIds from else where and stored in a different table:

```
mysql> create table so_OwnerUserId select distinct(Id) as OwnerUserId
from so_users order by RAND() limit 1000;
```

I have written the following query:

```
select @td := time_diff from so_time_diff sotd, so_OwnerUserId soui 
where sotd.OwnerUserId = soui.OwnerUserId group by sotd.OwnerUserId
order by rand() limit 1;
```

This doesn't seem to accomplish what I want. It obviously returns just one row. But I want one random row from each OwnerUserId's time_diff collection. Could someone guide me on how to accomplish this?

FYI - the size of dataset is huge - ~56m records. So I'm looking for an optimal query.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a correlated subquery. It's not a very efficient approach, since that subquery will be executed for each row in the outer table, which would be a 1000 times if there are 1000 rows in so_OwnerUserId.

```
SELECT r.OwnerUserId
     , ( SELECT d.time_diff
           FROM so_time_diff d
          WHERE d.OwnerUserId = r.OwnerUserId
          ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS random_time_diff
  FROM so_OwnerUserId r
```

For any kind of performance, you're going to need an index with a leading column of `OwnerUserId` on the `so_time_diff` table. Better yet, a covering index

```
... ON so_time_diff (OwnerUserId, time_diff)
```

(For InnoDB, if those are the only two columns in the table, you'd want that to be the cluster key.)